# sshpass failed to run command: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

I am trying to use sshpass to copy a file between VMs. However when I run the command:

`sshpass -p 'password' rsync --rsync-path="sudo rsync" "/home/myuser/anaconda/Anaconda2-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh" "user2@destination.vm":/opt`

I get the output: `sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory`

I can ssh to destination.vm using user2 and its password.

I know sshpass is installed at /usr/bin/sshpass and is on the path.

I double checked the folders I want to copy from and to exist. I have also successfully set up passwordless sudo by editing the sudoers file.

I’m at a bit of a loss on what else to do to troubleshoot. Do you have any suggestions? Is there something else I need to do to be able to run sshpass?

**EDIT:**

Thank you for the responses! I have installed rsync on destination.vm as suggested and tested it with the command:

```
rsync -v -e ssh test.txt localhost:~
```

However, I am still seeing the same message when I try to use sshpass. I have successfully used this command on a different system, but I'm not sure what is different about this one that prevents the command from working.

Comment: does it rsync work without `sshpass`?

Comment: @PabloMartinez yes it works without sshpass

Comment: (1) Do `ldd $(which sshpass)` and check all libraries resolve successfully and correctly. (2) Consider using publickey authentication, commony called passwordless, instead.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 The output of that is:    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdad663000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f42e4cf1000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f42e50b3000)

Comment: vdso is a special case and not resolving is okay. Not using anything other than libc is unusual but could be correct; I don't have a build on hand to check. Try something very simple like `sshpass /bin/pwd` and if that fails (as I expect) run it again with `strace` in front to see exactly where it is hitting the error. (And don't try to put that output in a comment, it will be unreadable; edit the Q.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 `sshpass /bin/pwd` worked. I got the output /home/myuser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install rsync on destination.vm

Comment: I installed rsync on destination.vm but I am still seeing the same message from sshpass

Comment: I installed rsync on the current vm in addition to bzip2 and now the command runs. Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The issue was resolved by removing the environment variables from .bashrc and directly adding them into the script.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in my case, Rsync package was not installed in source machine(not destination).